# Why is the FileExporter move button disabled on iOS16.1

Tags: swift, swiftui, ipados

When this code is run, the dialog box appears, but the `Move` button is disabled.

Has anyone else run across this problem on Xcode 14.1 beta 3 / iOS16.1 on the iPad simulator? Is there an obvious mistake? If not I'll raise a Feedback report with Apple.

[image]

```swift
import SwiftUI
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showFileExporter: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Export file")
                .onTapGesture {
                    showFileExporter = true
                }
                .fileExporter(isPresented: $showFileExporter, document: TextFile(), contentType: UTType.text) { result in }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct TextFile: FileDocument {
    static var readableContentTypes = [UTType.text]
    static var writableContentTypes = [UTType.text]
    
    var text = ""
    
    init() {}

    init(configuration: ReadConfiguration) throws {
        if let data = configuration.file.regularFileContents {
            text = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)
        }
    }
    
    func fileWrapper(configuration: WriteConfiguration) throws -> FileWrapper {
        let data = Data(text.utf8)
        return FileWrapper(regularFileWithContents: data)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just updated to beta 5 and the problem has been resolved. The button can be pressed again :)

Comment: Thank you! Just confirmed it with Xcode 14.1 and simulator running iOS 16.1 also.